# Accessing custom UIView button click action

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a custom `UIView` that replicates the behavior of a `UISegmentedControl`.

```
import UIKit
protocol CustomSegmentControlDelegate:class {
    func change(to index:Int)
}

class CustomSegmentControl: UIControl {
    
    private var buttonTitles:[String]!
    private var buttons: [UIButton]!
    private var selectorView: UIView!
    
    var textColor:UIColor = .black
    var selectorViewColor: UIColor = .green
    var selectorTextColor: UIColor = .green
    
    weak var delegate:CustomSegmentControlDelegate?
    
    public private(set) var selectedIndex : Int = 0
    
    convenience init(frame:CGRect,buttonTitle:[String]) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        self.buttonTitles = buttonTitle
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        updateView()
    }
    
    func setButtonTitles(buttonTitles:[String]) {
        self.buttonTitles = buttonTitles
        self.updateView()
    }
    
    func setIndex(index:Int) {
        buttons.forEach({ $0.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal) })
        let button = buttons[index]
        selectedIndex = index
        button.setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)
        let selectorPosition = frame.width/CGFloat(buttonTitles.count) * CGFloat(index)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.selectorView.frame.origin.x = selectorPosition
        }
    }
    

    
    @objc func buttonAction(sender:UIButton) {
        for (buttonIndex, btn) in buttons.enumerated() {
            btn.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
            if btn == sender {
                let selectorPosition = frame.width/CGFloat(buttonTitles.count) * CGFloat(buttonIndex)
                selectedIndex = buttonIndex
                delegate?.change(to: selectedIndex)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.selectorView.frame.origin.x = selectorPosition
                }
                btn.setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)
                
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Within a separate View Controller with this UIView added, I am currently unable to listen for the UIViews action and deal with the button clicks. `buttonAction` does get called. The below function does not get called on click.

View is added to the VC with:

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentView: CustomSegmentControl!


func change(to index: Int) {
        print("Inside the function")
    }
```

Comment: Can you show me how you are initializing the view in your separate View Controller and set the delegate?

Comment: Please add the obvious details: Is `delegate` set, does `buttonAction` gets called, ...?

Comment: I've added the view initialization, delegate is not currently set.

Comment: The delegate may not be working, you have added segmentView.delegate = self when addsubview segmentView?